# parse_markdown and truncate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redcarpet

I have to use at the same time parse_markdown and truncate.
My text is (for example)

```
"Hi **boys**, I am very happy to be <a href="/here">here<a/> with you. I am so proud of you and your work."
```

If I use

```
<%= parse_markdown(truncate(@city.last_news.text, length: 30, separator: ' ')).html_safe %>
```

I see

```
Hi **boys**, I am very happy to be <a href="/here">here<a/> with you. I am so proud of you and your work.
```

with the markdown but without the truncate.

and if I use

```
<%= truncate(parse_markdown(@city.last_news.text).html_safe, length: 30, separator: ' ') %>
```

I see

```
    Hi **boys**, I am very happy to be <a href="/here">here<a/> with yo...
```

with the truncatebut without the markdown.

How to solve?

Comment: There is no simple solution to this -- blindly truncating at a set length makes it likely you will truncate a portion of the mark up.

Answer (score -1):

I was using [this gem](https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html) to truncate html. If you can manage to get it working today (latest commit is from 5 years ago), this will solve one part of your problem. Idk if it can be useful for markdown too. Try it out

Example usage:

```
%p
  = truncate_html(document.description, length: 200)
```